# Text Parser c++ code

Tags: c++, parsing, text

I need a C++ code for the following problem:
i have a text file that i want to start reading from a specific line, then i need to print the output located between the characters --- <\s>
example:  hello<\s>
i want the output to be  hello

I think i should use text parser but not sure how!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    std::string line_;
    ifstream file_("tty.txt");
    if (file_.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(file_, line_))
        {
            std::cout << line_ << '\n';

        }

        file_.close();

    }
    else
    std::cout << "error" << '\n';
    std::cin.get();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you do seem to be in need of a parser. What have you tried to do, in order to parse the text?

Comment: Something like [`std::regex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex) may be?

Comment: Don't see a relationship between description & example string with the expected output. Do you need a text inside two `<\s>` or what?

Comment: My first thought was regex as well.

Comment: If the delimiters are simple text, just search for them. `std::string` can do that very simply; no need for the overhead and complexity of regular expressions.

Comment: Incidentally, the code doesn't need to check `if(file_.is_open())`; the call to `getline` will fail if the file wasn't opened. And the call to `file_.close()` isn't needed: the `ifstream` destructor will do that.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy Yes i need to extract the text between the <s> text<\s>

Answer (score 0):

You can load all text in one variable, and then with regex search all occurences of your desired pattern (in your case `<sth>(any_aplha_numeric_character)*</sth>` where `*` means one or more occurence, you can read about it at any std::regex tutorial)

Example:

```
std::smatch m;          
std::string text = "<a>adsd</a>  <a>esd</a>";
std::string::const_iterator searchStart(text.cbegin());
std::regex rgx("<a>[A-Za-z0-9\\s]*</a>");

while (std::regex_search(searchStart, text.cend(), m, rgx))
{
    cout << m[0] << endl;
    searchStart += m.position() + m.length();
}
```

gives: `<a>adsd</a>` and `<a>esd</a>` as a result, from which is very easy to extract that inner string